# Create Excel graph from updated data on changing input value

Tags: excel, graph

This is the thing: I do have an energy model. The outcome is data (Watt) of the losses of energy by wall, floor, windows, ventilation, roof. The changing part in my model is the outside temperature. I did write a macro which changes this temperature from -10 to 10 Celcius. In a normal pie-chart this works nicely. So the temperature field changes and the values for wall, floor etc are updated in their respective fields.

But this is what I need: I want a graph (line or scatter) that will display: temperature (x-axis) and power (Watt, y-axis) for all 5 (wall, floor, etc) places where I lose energy.

How to do this? Can i (do i have to) collect the data and then at the end present it in a graph? Or can i tell excel to extend the graph with each new values when temperature is changed? At this point i can only display the actual data in the fields more or less.

I hope you understand my question and that someone can point me in the right direction.

This is the code I came up with so far:

```
Sub BtnBuitenTemp()
Dim PauseTime, Start

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets(1)

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Sheets(2)

Dim cell As Range

' loop through temperature values given on Sheet(2)
' for now these range from -10 to 10
For Each cell In ws2.Range("A20:A40")

    ' update values in temperature cell
    ws1.Cells.Range("D10").Value = cell.Value

    ' add some pause
    PauseTime = 1
    Start = Timer

    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
Next

End Sub
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

The orange part in "Temperaturen" is changed by the macro. Thereby all other data will be updated and displayed in the chart. The chart will only update the y-axis values at this point. I would like to loop the temperature range (and display this as well on the x-axis) and keep the former values in the chart at their respective temperatures. (I also am not able to display the x-axis range.)

(update)

Ok, I do have a XY (scatter) graph now and I can set the x axis. This is what I do have so far:

```
Sub BtnBuitenTemp()

Dim PauseTime, Start

Dim tbu_min As Integer
Dim tbu_max As Integer

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets(1)

' get user values for min and max temp
tbu_min = ws1.Range("TempBuitenMin").Value
tbu_max = ws1.Range("TempBuitenMax").Value

' set chart x axis values to user input
With ws1.ChartObjects("Chart 7").Chart
    With .Axes(xlCategory)
        .MinimumScale = tbu_min
        .MaximumScale = tbu_max
    End With
End With

For temp = tbu_min To tbu_max
    ' update values in temperature cell
    ws1.Cells.Range("D10").Value = temp

    ' add some pause
    PauseTime = 0.5
    Start = Timer

    Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
        DoEvents
    Loop
Next temp

End Sub
```

And that looks like:

[image]

Now I only need to update the data on the right temperature...

- update 2  -

I updated my data for the xy scatter graph. I forgot to insert the "Series X Values". Now the right is displayed at the right temperature. I now only need to keep the output in view; at this moment it does refresh the graph each time.

[image]

Comment: If you could add your code and some screenshots, I'd be a great support for us to help you! ;) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sry for that. Updated.

Comment: Ok so you only have a part of a row or column that will be one data point of your data series. And I guess the values that are recalculated when temparature changes are overwrite at the same place? Can you tell us where that is? The address of the range would be good : like C3:C9 or something! ;)

Comment: I hope i do understand you well... The values are recalculated indeed for each new temperature. That looks like this (for the roof i.e.):

`=J41*J9*(D12-D10)`

Where J41 is some given value and J9 is the surface of the roof. D12 is the given inside temperature and D10 is the changing outside temp.

Comment: Ok and what is the range where these calculations are done? I.E. Where are these formulas in your excel sheet?

Comment: They are all over the place. I did group all stuff belonging together; then calculate some stuff and the result is in a field.

Comment: ... the final result is in these fields. I'll add a image in my post.

wall = O24, floor = O47, windows = O61, ventilation = O68, roof = O35

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did solve my problem. Not the way I wanted it, but I do not have time left to find another way. I now just collect all the data and draw a chart from within my macro. This is a prototype that does the trick.

```
Sub BtnBuitenTemp()

Dim PauseTime, Start

Dim tbu_min As Integer
Dim tbu_max As Integer

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = Sheets(1)

Dim dataSize As Integer
Dim dataCounter As Integer

Dim myChartObject As ChartObject

Dim addTotal As Boolean

' get user values for min and max temp
tbu_min = ws1.Range("TempBuitenMin").Value
tbu_max = ws1.Range("TempBuitenMax").Value

' how many datapoints are there
Dim xPoints() As Integer

' add surfaces
Dim muur() As Integer
Dim vloer() As Integer
Dim ramen() As Integer
Dim dak() As Integer
Dim ventilatie() As Integer
Dim totaal() As Integer

dataSize = Abs(tbu_max - tbu_min)

ReDim xPoints(dataSize)

ReDim muur(dataSize)
ReDim vloer(dataSize)
ReDim ramen(dataSize)
ReDim dak(dataSize)
ReDim ventilatie(dataSize)
ReDim totaal(dataSize)



' collect data
dataCounter = 0
For temp = tbu_min To tbu_max

    ' update values in temperature cell
    ws1.Cells.Range("D10").Value = temp
    ' add x for series
    xPoints(dataCounter) = temp

    ' add data for y series
    muur(dataCounter) = ws1.Cells.Range("O24").Value
    vloer(dataCounter) = ws1.Cells.Range("O47").Value
    ramen(dataCounter) = ws1.Cells.Range("O61").Value
    dak(dataCounter) = ws1.Cells.Range("O35").Value
    ventilatie(dataCounter) = ws1.Cells.Range("O68").Value
    totaal(dataCounter) = ws1.Cells.Range("O74").Value

    ' next
    dataCounter = dataCounter + 1

Next temp


' ask to add total
If MsgBox("Wil je ook het totaal tonen in de grafiek?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    addTotal = True
Else
    addTotal = False
End If


If Not ChartExists(ws1, "buitentemperatuur") Then
    ' Chart does not exist, create chart

     With ws1.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=200, Width:=600, Top:=200, Height:=400)
        With .chart
            .Parent.Name = "buitentemperatuur"
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = False
            .Axes(xlCategory).Crosses = xlMinimum
            .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
            .HasLegend = True
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = "Invloed van de buitentemperatuur"

        End With
    End With
End If

' Chart does exist, remove old series and update chart
ws1.ChartObjects("buitentemperatuur").Activate
For Each s In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    s.Delete
Next s

 With ws1.ChartObjects("buitentemperatuur")
    With .chart

         .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScaleIsAuto = True

         With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "muur"
            .XValues = xPoints
            .Values = muur
         End With

         With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "vloer"
            .XValues = xPoints
            .Values = vloer
         End With

         With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "ramen"
            .XValues = xPoints
            .Values = ramen
         End With

         With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "dak"
            .XValues = xPoints
            .Values = dak
         End With

         With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "ventilatie"
            .XValues = xPoints
            .Values = ventilatie
         End With

         If addTotal Then
            With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .Name = "totaal"
                .XValues = xPoints
                .Values = totaal
            End With
        End If

    End With
End With


End Sub

Function ChartExists(wsTest As Worksheet, strChartName As String) As Boolean
Dim chTest As ChartObject

On Error Resume Next
Set chTest = wsTest.ChartObjects(strChartName)
On Error GoTo 0

If chTest Is Nothing Then
    ChartExists = False
Else
    ChartExists = True
End If

End Function
```